# フォルダを指定するダイアログを出して、選択したフォルダのファイルをすべて読み込む用に変更したら、400エラーが出てしまいました。

Tags: vba

元々は、マクロが入っているフォルダの中にある、エクセルフォイルを読み込んで、
処理を進めていくプログラムだったのですが、自分で、任意のフォルダを選択して、
その中に、入っているすべてのファイルの値を取得できるように変えたら、400エラーが出てしまいました。
ご教授お願いいたします。

```
Sub 単体テスト仕様書マクロ()
Dim wFile       As String
Dim wFilePath   As String
Dim i           As Long
 
'Excelファイルが存在していたらファイル名を返す
wFile = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.xlsx")
Sheets("単体テスト仕様書").Range("A2:D31").ClearContents
'先頭行を指定
i = 2

  Dim folderPath As Variant
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
  .Show
  folderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
  End With
 
'選択したフォルダに存在するExcelファイルを全て読み込む
Do While folderPath <> ""
     
    '開くExcelファイルのフルパスを取得
    wFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & folderPath
     
    '機能（ﾌﾟﾛｸﾞﾗﾑ）名・テスト件数・完了数・不具合件数を取得し配列に格納する（区切り文字：|）
    strData = Split(File_Load(wFilePath), "|")
     
    '機能（ﾌﾟﾛｸﾞﾗﾑ）名
    Cells(i, 1) = strData(0)
     
    'テスト件数
    Cells(i, 2) = strData(1)
     
    '完了数
    Cells(i, 3) = strData(2)
    
    '不具合件数
    
    Cells(i, 4) = strData(3)
      
     
    '次のExcelファイルを取得
    wFile = Dir()
     
    '行数をカウント
    i = i + 1
 
Loop
 
    MsgBox "完了"
End Sub

Function File_Load(ByVal wFilePath As String) As String

    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim wItem       As Variant
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim FoundCell   As Object

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wFilePath)

    wItem = Array("機能（ﾌﾟﾛｸﾞﾗﾑ）名", "テスト件数", "完了数", "不具合件数")

    For i = LBound(wItem) To UBound(wItem)

        Set FoundCell = wb.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:=wItem(i))

        If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            wItem(i) = ""
        Else
            wItem(i) = FoundCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
        End If

    Next i

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    File_Load = Join(wItem, "|")


End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`folderPath`にはフォルダパスが入ります。
例えば開いているExcelマクロ有効ファイルが`C:\hoge\fuga.xlsm`に保存されていて
ダイアログで選択したフォルダが`C:\fuga`だとすると
`wFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & folderPath`で代入される`wFilePath`変数の値は
`C:\hoge\C:\fuga`という**無効なパス**になります。

選択したフォルダ内部のファイル一覧を取得するにはDir関数を使用してください。
http://officetanaka.net/excel/vba/file/file07.htm

```
'Excelファイルが存在していたらファイル名を返す
'この行は不要 wFile = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.xlsx")

Sheets("単体テスト仕様書").Range("A2:D31").ClearContents
'先頭行を指定
i = 2

Dim folderPath As Variant
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    folderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    'TODO キャンセル時の処理を入れた方が良いと思います
End With

wFile = Dir(folderPath & "\*.xlsx")

'選択したフォルダに存在するExcelファイルを全て読み込む
Do While wFile <> "" 

    '開くExcelファイルのフルパスを取得
    wFilePath = folderPath & "\" & wFile

    '機能（ﾌﾟﾛｸﾞﾗﾑ）名・テスト件数・完了数・不具合件数を取得し配列に格納する（区切り文字：|）
    strData = Split(File_Load(wFilePath), "|")
```

Comment: 丁寧に教えてくださり、ありがとうございます。無事にできました。また、機会がありましたら、よろしくお願いします。